# How to transfer date parameters within JSON? Formatted as long?

Tags: java, json, rest, date-format, datetime-format

I was looking around for something like a convention of how to transfer a date parameter via REST using JSON as body content type. I see some are using `long` as I was on couple of places where I wrote both client and server side code. I find this approach most convenient.

I want to avoid potential problems when it comes to date formats etc. Is it all up to arrangement between client and server side producers or something can be used as most correct approach?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Can you do that? Sure you can. Should you? It's a matter of taste. I find it less readable than an ISO date.

Comment: Its inside subject. + I want to avoid potential problems when it comes to date formats etc.

Comment: So you ask how to transfer dates, but the only acceptable answer is "formatted as long". So you answered your own question, didn't you? By formatting dates as longs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your needs, you could use a Unix timestamp since epoch, that is, the number of seconds elapsed since January 1, 1970 (midnight UTC/GMT).

But if you want to use something *more readable*, consider the [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard, which is endorsed by the [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) and by the [xkcd 1179](https://xkcd.com/1179/):

[image: xkcd 1179: ISO 8601]

Comment: I take it that 1330300800 under the discouraged formats denotes seconds since the epoch. Which tends to suggest that formatting as a long is discouraged too.

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard for internet date and times: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339
ISO 8601 is the canonical format...